# How to subset a data frame to select specific information from each column in R?

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have a data frame like the below:

```
ID  B1  B2  B3
1   aa  a1  0
2   aa  a1  1
3   aa  a2  0
4   aa  a2  3
5   aa  a2  1
6   aa  a2  0
7   aa  a2  2
8   aa  a3  2
9   aa  a3  1
10  aa  a3  0
11  aa  a3  9
12  ab  a1  1
13  ab  a2  0
14  ab  a2  0
15  ab  a2  3
16  ab  a3  4
17  ac  a1  1
18  ac  a1  0
19  ac  a1  0
20  ac  a1  1
21  ac  a1  5
22  ac  a1  0
23  ac  a1  1
24  ac  a1  3
25  ac  a2  0
26  ac  a2  1
27  ac  a3  2
28  ac  a3  0
29  ac  a3  6
30  ac  a3  3
```

And I want to select instances where B1= aa, B2=a1 and B3>=1.
How can I use "filter" or "subset" for several conditions?

Thanks

Comment: `filter` is ok for what you need, just try and see if you obtain what you need

Answer (score 1):

Both work:
`df1=subset(df, B1=="aa" & B2=="a1" & B3>=1)` or `df1=filter(df, B1=="aa" & B2=="a1" & B3>=1)`